# Help with Boolean Expression Simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

I know that

$$(\neg a \land \neg b \land \neg c) \lor (a \land \neg b \land c) \lor (\neg a \land b \land \neg c) \lor (a \land b \land c )$$

and

$$(\neg a \land \neg b \land \neg c) \lor (a \land c) \lor (\neg a \land b \land \neg c)$$

are supposed to be equal but I'm unsure how to simplify the first boolean expression past cancelling the first and last terms due to the identity rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that:

$$\begin{align}
(a\land b\land c)\lor (a\land \lnot b\land c) 
& = ((a\land c)\land b)\lor((a\land c)\land\lnot b) & \textsf{association and commutation}
\\
& = (a\land c)\land (b\lor\lnot b) & \textsf{distribution} \\ & = (a\land c) \land \top & \textsf{complementation} \\ & = a\land c & \textsf{conjunctive identity}
\end{align}$$

Now can you use this lesson to further simplify your statement?

Comment: That helped, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$(a∧¬b∧c)∨(a∧b∧c)$ = $(a∧c)∧(¬b∨b)$ = $(a∧c)$

use this to get to your answer